# How can I count lines containing a case-insensitive match for a word, excluding any lines with case-sensitive matches?

Tags: shell, unix

I am working on the sonnets of Shakespeare in a file. I tried to look for a string in the file which is "Rose" and "rose".

First, I have constructed a command to find the line numbers in sonnets.txt file where the string "rose" appears, the command was as follows:

```
~$ grep rose sonnets.txt | wc
```

The output was 10.

Then,  I tried to execute a command that shows the number of lines contain the string "Rose" using a case-sensitive grep for "rose", which is as follows:

```
~$ grep -i rose sonnets.txt | wc
```

The output was 12.

Which means the number of string for "Rose" is 2. But after running a command it said there were 3. After analysing, I found out that there are "Rose" and "rose" string in the same line.

Can you please help me with a command confirming that the number of lines matching "Rose" but not matching "rose" is equal to the expected 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pipe to filter out the rows with both.

```
grep Rose sonnets.txt | grep -v rose | wc -l
```

you can also use the `-c` option to `grep` if you just want a count.

```
grep Rose sonnets.txt | grep -v -c rose
```